# Speed up Manipulate when aspect ratio of graphics > 100?

Tags: plotting, manipulate

Using:

```
displaylength = 20000;
displayheight = 40;
length = 50000;
height = 40;
a = Table[RandomReal[], height, length];
Manipulate[
 ArrayPlot[a, ImageSize -> {1000, 200}, AspectRatio -> Full, 
 PlotRange -> {{1, displayheight}, {i, i + displaylength}}], {i, 1, 
 length - displaylength, 1}]
```

the output looks nice and the slider is very responsive:

[image]

But as soon as `displayheight` is set to `39`, the output changes, is drawn very slow and the responsiveness of the slider is terrible:

[image: Notice that displayheight is set to 39 below the plot]

This is exactly the breaking point when the aspect ratio of the plot goes beyond 100.

What is the reason for this? Is it dependent on the graphic card? How to avoid it (without limiting the aspect ratio)?

p.s. The problem is still there in version 11.
p.p.s. Running on 64bit Windows 7 using NVIDIA GeForce 210

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: I get the same performance with `displayheight`=39. I am on windows 7 64 bit with a NVIDIA Quadro K4000 graphics card. Also works using 20 for `displayheight`.

Comment: @JackLaVigne I need `displayheight = 19` to trigger it in 10.1.0 under Windows.

Answer (score 4):

As a workaround you can use `Image*` functions:

```
displaylength = 20000;
displayheight = 40;
length = 50000;
height = 39;
a = Table[RandomReal[], height, length];

Manipulate[
  ImageResize[
     ImageTake[
       Image[a], {1, displayheight}, {i, i + displaylength}
     ], 
     {1000, 200}
  ], 
  {i, 1, length - displaylength, 1}
]
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) I would add `Magnification -> 1` into the `Image` for such purposes. In any case it is worth to mention this option here.

Comment: (+1) Nice workaround.

Comment: For my purpose adding `Sampling->"Constant"` to `ImageResize` was required. Otherwise zooming into the display would not show tiles as it should.

Answer (score 1):

In version 10.1.0 under Windows one can reduce the example to this:

```
a = RandomReal[1, {20, 600}];

Table[
  Graphics[Raster[a], ImageSize -> {600, h}, AspectRatio -> Full]
  , {h, {200, 210}}
] // Column
```

[image]

I cannot find a description of this transition in the documentation.  I shall see if I can find anything else useful to note.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the `PixelConstrained` option to speed up `ArrayPlot` in this instance.

```
displayheight = 39;
Manipulate[
 ArrayPlot[a, ImageSize -> {1000, 200}, AspectRatio -> Full, 
  PlotRange -> {{1, displayheight}, {i, i + displaylength}}, 
  PixelConstrained -> 4], 
 {i, 1, length - displaylength, 1}]
```

I'm not total certain why this happens but it appears that `displayheight = 39` does not agree with `ArrayPlot`'s default display options.  If you explicitly set the pixel alignment with `PixelConstrained` then it has no difficulties working out where to paint the cells.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This doesn't appear to affect the underlying issue.  For example with `displayheight = 15;` and `PixelConstrained -> 20` I get the same transition to hard banding and the same slow-down while moving the slider.

Comment: Agree, PixelContrained helps only in some setups of the parameters. In `ArrayPlot[RandomReal[1, {20, 600}], ImageSize -> {600, 102}, 
 AspectRatio -> Full, PixelConstrained -> 4]` PixelConstrained is not helping.